# Clean the website Domain - still showing old files

Tags: asp.net, dns, web

We have a website developed in php many years ago.We now redeveloped the website using asp.net.
I have published the website and everything work fine now.

Lately, I see there are several requests hitting the site with old urls(php).
I did submit the sitemap to all the major search engines but the requests to the old URLs still keep coming every few weeks mstky from bing now.

When I checked the bing webmaster tools, my domain  folder structure still shows the php folders and files alomg with the new asp.net folders/files .So I assume that whenever the spiderbots  are crawling my webiste, all thesse files are hit and logs the errors.

My question is why  are the old files still showing up when they are not physically present in the filesystem( Hosted them on IIS) and the php folders dont even exists here.
How do I clean the domain and come out of this problem as the log files keep growing unnecessarily?

Comment: This question have nothing to do with programming, and you talk about google webmaster tools - all crawlers keep a history of your links and have a schedule to index them. Your links will leave this query after some time. The correct way to do that is **to keep your php files and add them inside a permanent move redirect header**. If you do not show to your crawler that the files gone for ever, with a redirect, then the crawler will think that your server have a problem, and you lose and your old position on search

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed that Bing seems to remember those pages for a long time even if they give a 404 or 301 HTTP result. It's not because Bing remembers those pages that they are shown in the search results.

404 errors are the least of your worries. Lot's of bots will come to your site and request pages that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

When you like to change a page from `example.php` to `example.aspx` the "correct way" to not lose your indexes on crawlers, and also do not lose your users bookmarks is to make a permanently redirect on each page that you going to change location.

for php that will be :

```
<?php
 header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
 header("Location: http://example.org/example.aspx");
?>
```

So you need to add that on each of your old php pages, and move them to the new location.

Crawlers will keep the old links, and even if they are not on index, even they are not exist, they will be looking for them for long time. When they decide that is not a web error, and they are gone for ever they will be deletes them, until then you will continue to see them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I did implement 301 redirect in my new site but i am still not sure how is bing showing the folder structure of the old urls when they done exist anymore??

Comment: @Krishna if it do not exist, how you have make the 301 redirect ?

Comment: @Aritos  implemented using httpRedirect in the config file.